# Ordering data after an intersection Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a db homework question. It asks that the data be in descending order. However, I'm using an intersection in my query because of the many to many relationship.

The schema for Genre is

```
CREATE TABLE Genre (
movie_id integer REFERENCES Movie(id),
genre GenreType,
primary key (movie_id,genre)
);
```

My code is currently

```
    $genres = tokenise($argv[1], "&");
    $i = 0;
    $qry = " 
        (select m.title, m.YEAR, m.content_rating, m.lang, r.imdb_score, r.num_voted_users
        from Movie m
        join Rating r on (m.id = r.movie_id)
        join Genre g on (m.id = g.movie_id)
        where m.YEAR >= ".$startYear." 
        and m.YEAR <= ".$endYear." 
        and g.genre = '".$genres[$i]."')
        ";
    $i++;
    while ($i < count($genres)){
        $qry = $qry."
            intersect
            (select m.title, m.YEAR, m.content_rating, m.lang, r.imdb_score, r.num_voted_users
            from Movie m
            join Rating r on (m.id = r.movie_id)
            join Genre g on (m.id = g.movie_id)
            where m.YEAR >= ".$startYear." 
            and m.YEAR <= ".$endYear." 
            and g.genre = '".$genres[$i]."')
            ";
        $i++;
    }
```

I'd like to order the final result with the statement

```
order by r.imdb_score desc, r.num_voted_users desc
```

However, tagging it onto the end of each select statement doesn't work (the output is still scrambled).

Comment: Update: I've got a temp solution which is creating it as a view and doing another query. But I'm still curious if you can order the output without a second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intersect (or union or except) can only have a single `ORDER BY` at the end. Even if it "looks like" it belongs to the final query, it applies to the whole result, e.g.:

```
select m.title, m.YEAR, m.content_rating, m.lang, r.imdb_score, r.num_voted_users
from Movie m
  join Rating r on m.id = r.movie_id
  join Genre g on m.id = g.movie_id
where ...

intersect

select m.title, m.YEAR, m.content_rating, m.lang, r.imdb_score, r.num_voted_users
from Movie m
  join Rating r on m.id = r.movie_id
  join Genre g on m.id = g.movie_id
where ...

order by imdb_score desc, num_voted_users desc
```

Will sort the complete result of the intersect, note that you can't use a table alias when referencing the columns (and the column names correspond to the name from the first query).

Putting the individual queries between parentheses is not needed.

---

But the use of `intersect` seems strange to begin with.

It seems you are simulating a simple `IN` condition with that. As far as I can tell, you could replace that with a single query that uses `where ... and genre in ('genre1', 'genre2', ....)`

It will be easier to understand and it will also be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know "in" conditions existed. Think that will help out for the next question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do something like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   [Your_Entire_Query_With_All_Your_Intersects]
) T
ORDER BY [Your_Conditions];
```

But I don't know exactly what you want to do. Your query seems quite odd to me. Why the intersect in the first place?